# Parameterized queries in sqlite3 using question marks

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, parameterized-query

I am using sqlite3 module with Python and have this code so far. In the database I have stored daily weather conditions, and now I need my code to replace some rows with updated data. The code is supposed to be looking for the row with `datetime` value equal to `new_data[0]`.

The way I parameterized the query is wrong, but cannot figure out the correct and most elegant way of going about it!

```
new_data = ['12 Mar 2014', 'sunny', 20, 12]

conn = sqlite3.connect(database_file)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("UPDATE weather SET datetime = ?, condition = ?, high = ?, low = ? WHERE datetime = %s" new_data, %new_data[0])
```

Comment: no need to set datetime again  if is is same

Answer (score 9):

You are mixin up a parameterized query with string operations. First, that's highly insecure and second, you have created a problem with your syntax (you missed a comma after your query string). Try this instead:

```
new_data = ('12 Mar 2014', 'sunny', 20, 12, '12 Mar 2014',)

conn = sqlite3.connect(database_file)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("UPDATE weather SET datetime = ?, condition = ?, high = ?, low = ? WHERE datetime = ?", new_data)
```

More details can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html